# Многосайтовость Битрикс, две языковые версии

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть сайт на русском языке site.ru. Задача сделать английскую версию. Среди нескольких способов выбрал такой:

1. Создал поддомен en.site.ru
2. Создал папку в корне сайта назвал "en".
3. Сделал символьные ссылки для папок bitrix и upload.
4. Скопировал все содержимое кроме папок bitrix и upload(также .htaccess, .access и тд), шаблоны у меня в папке local.
5. Создал второй сайт в админке назвал "en".[image: введите сюда описание изображения] В разделе Шаблон сайта у шаблонов названия такие же как и на основном (надо ли их переименовывать или создавать отдельно для англ версии?). Что на русской версии что на англ шаблоны выглядят вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. Вот настройки основного сайта[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
7. Копировал вместе с содержимым инфоблоки для английской версии. Поменял iblock id для этих инфоблоков. Поставил нужные галочки напротив сайта английской версии.
8. Все ! Больше абсолютно ничего не делал (может быть что-то упустил?)

Теперь о проблемах:
1. Навигация. В режиме правки на сайте en.site.ru пункты меню перевожу на англ и сохраняю. Но на сайте остается все на русском языке. Хотя еще раз нажав на редактировать пункты меню там все остается на английском, но на сайте повторюсь все остается на русском.
2. Каталог товаров. Меняя инфоблок для одного из сайтов инфоблок меняется и для другого, таким образом на одном из сайтов выводит неверный информационный блок, на другом выводит товары.
3. В прочем со всеми остальными элементами и страницами проблема та же.

В чем может быть причина? Я так подозреваю что не подключается шаблон англ сайта, но не могу понять почему.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что создание английской версии сайта в Битриксе на поддомене - это довольно сложная штука. Если хотите, можете попробовать с помощью документации решить эту задачу:

> В некоторых случаях бывает необходимо организовать [выделение некоторых разделов сайта в виде поддомена](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=103&LESSON_ID=290&LESSON_PATH=8799.3987.290) основного сайта. Например, организовать форум не по адресу www.mysite.ru/forum/, а по адресу forum.mysite.ru. Задача решается с использованием методов [многосайтовости на разных доменах](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=103&LESSON_ID=287&LESSON_PATH=8799.3987.287).

То есть по сути это должны быть разные сайты на разных доменах.

Гораздо проще создать в рамках существующего сайта папку /en/, туда перенести всю английскую версию, создать для этой папки отдельный шаблон, со своим меню (пути в меню должны начинаться с /en/).

Теперь что касается инфоблоков. Не очень понял фразу **Копировал вместе с содержимым инфоблоки для английской версии**. В документации [однозначно сказано](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2915):

```
В Bitrix Framework штатно не предусмотрена возможность копирования инфоблоков
```

Вам либо пришлось бы проделывать все те манипуляции, которые описаны в документации (что Вы вряд ли делали), либо на самом деле Вы ничего не скопировали и выводите на обоих сайтах одну и ту же информацию.

Для английской версии Вам надо вручную создать новый инфоблок и вручную же занести в него все товары. И уже этот инфоблок выводить на английской версии.

Comment: Обязательно ли делать символьную ссылку для папки local? Если на сайтах будет разный контент, например картинки...

Comment: @RomanMaksimov, поясните, что Вы имеете в виду? Для чего Вам вообще папка local? Все шаблоны в Битриксе лежат в папке /bitrix/templates/

Comment: Сайт делал не я, все шаблоны (их там 3) лежат в папке local/templates, меня интересует вообще в принципе допустимо не создавать символьную ссылку, а копировать папку local?

Comment: @RomanMaksimov, я так не пробовал делать - всегда через /bitrix/templates/ работаю. Можете скопировать /local/ и посмотреть, что получится. Или просто добавить шаблон английской версии в /bitrix/templates/ и подключить оттуда.

Answer (score 0):

> При определении сайта каждый элемент этого списка интерпретируется как корневой домен (например, значение site.com будет означать www.site.com, my.site.com, ...)

Видимо при заходе на en.site.ru он подхватывает сайт site.ru, поскольку он идет первым

Comment: Как это исправить?

Comment: например использовать ru.site.ru и en.site.ru, или сделать мультиязычность на отдельных каталогах типа site.ru/en. Можно попробовать в списке сайтов поменять сортировку, чтобы en.site.ru был выше

Comment: Спасибо за ответ сортировка у en.site.ru = 100 , у  site.ru = 500, не помогает