# Мультиязычность на Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, мультиязычность

Подскажите как лучше реализовать такой сайт. ?
Контент одинаковый.
Вижу два варианта

1. Под каждый язык свой сайт
2. Доп свойства для английского в инфоблоках.

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1043697/178576) [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/979002/178576) [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/953608/178576)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Мультиязычность в bitrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1043697/%d0%9c%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-bitrix)

Answer (score 0):

Если делать самому , то это будет костыльный метод на свойствах, так как вы хотите. Представьте если вы так сделаете, то что будет например с СЕО свойствами?

Еще задайтесь вопросом. Если это каталог, то как будет с фильтром?  Ведь будут дубли свойств. Поэтому полноценного решения как кроме того что я описал ниже - нет.

Вот решение вашего вопроса. [https://bxproger.ru/~fGFnv](https://bxproger.ru/%7EfGFnv)
Мы создали полноценный модуль Мультиязычности для Битрикс.

И еще, если делать под каждый язык свой сайт, то учтите что если у вас будут скидки например, то придется делать разные для каждого сайта.

И если вы предоставите купон на скидку, то применить его будет только на одном языке, так как у вас каждый язык - это отдельный сайт.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/818775)